# Unroll the loop of Tensorflow to avoid frequent GPU kernel overhead

Tags: tensorflow

Consider the following program which I iteratively compute `b += a` for a number of iterations.

```
A = tf.constant(np.random.randn(1000000))
B = tf.constant(np.random.randn(1000000))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init)
  for i in range(100):
    B = tf.add(A, B)
```

Clearly, the above loop invokes at least 100 times kernel launch which sees non-necessary because I am actually doing this addition in place. Is there any way to avoid kernel launch overhead? Ideally I am looking for a tensorflow API solution (with only one call on `run`), not changing the logic of `B += a`.

Comment: Have you considered creating the random samples as a tensor and then indexing over subsets of the tensor for each element of the loop? I think you can use epochs for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`tf.while_loop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop).

```
i = tf.constant(100)
op = tf.while_loop(
  lambda a, b, i: tf.greater(i, 0),
  lambda a, b, i: (a+b, b, i-1),
  (a, b, i))
res = op[0]
```

`res` contains the "value of `a`" after running the loop -- beware that `a` is actually unchanged and still contains the starting value.

Comment: I saw from the official website that this function is run in parallel. However, I do need the dependency between iteration. Can u instruct me how to get there?

Comment: The number of parallel operations can be controled via the `parallel_iterations` argument of the function. You could set it to `1` if needed. However in the present case I doubt you will notice any difference in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you're creating 100 assign and addition operations in your graph and this is probably not what you want.

This piece of code should do what you want.

```
    A = tf.constant(np.random.randn(1000000))
    # B has to be a variable so we can assign to it
    B = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(1000000))

    # Add the assign and addition operators to the graph
    assign_to_B_op = B.assign(tf.add(A, B)) 

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        # To ensure we don't add new ops to the Graph by mistake.
        sess.graph.finalize()
        sess.run(init)
        for i in range(100):
            sess.run(assign_to_B_op)
            print(B.eval())
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to learn about TF is that you need to separate the definition of the graph from its execution. It will save you hours of debugging/searching for inefficiencies later when you will work on the real problems.

You current problem is because you have not done this. In your loop you create a graph node each time (100 times). If you want - check your tensorboard graph if you are lazy just increase the value to a very big one and your program will crash with something like `graph is bigger than 2Gb`.

To do this in a better way you define and then execute. To reassign the value you use assign operator.

```
A = tf.constant(3) # change to your random stuff
B = tf.Variable(1) # change to your random stuff
B_new = B.assign(tf.add(A, B)) 

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(100):
        res = sess.run(B_new)
    print res
```

And at last you clearly do not need a loop:

```
A = tf.constant(3)
B = tf.constant(1)
C = 100 * A + B

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run(C)
```